# Memory leak in Htmlunit 2.27

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am using `htmlunit`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>
```

I have simple loop which every one second print some data from response:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        WebClient webClient;

        webClient = new WebClient();

        webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        final History window = webClient.getWebWindows().get(0).getHistory();
        final Field f;
        try {
            f = window.getClass().getDeclaredField("ignoreNewPages_"); //NoSuchFieldException
            f.setAccessible(true);
            ((ThreadLocal<Boolean>) f.get(window)).set(Boolean.TRUE);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://stackoverflow.com");
            System.out.println(page.getHead().toString());

            Thread.sleep(1000);

            webClient.getCookieManager().clearCookies();
            webClient.getCache().clear();

            final List<WebWindow> windows = webClient.getWebWindows();

            for (final WebWindow wd : windows) {

                wd.getJobManager().removeAllJobs();

            }

            webClient.close();

        }
    }
```

When I run the program, memory is growing, why? It is bug? Or what?

Comment: Have a look at: https://maxrohde.com/2013/01/05/fix-htmlunit-memory-leak/

Comment: It is the natural behavior. You can take a look at the source code of HtmlPage. https://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/code/HEAD/tree/branches/htmlunit3/htmlunit/src/main/java/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.java#l137
It contains all the objects that are parsed from `webClient.getPage`. All these objects are recreated every second. So, the objects stay in memory until GC collects garbage. Therefore, increasing the memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://stackoverflow.com");
    System.out.println(page.getHead().toString());

    Thread.sleep(1000);

    webClient.getCookieManager().clearCookies();
    webClient.getCache().clear();

    final List<WebWindow> windows = webClient.getWebWindows();

    for (final WebWindow wd : windows) {
        wd.getJobManager().removeAllJobs();
    }
}
```

As per the above loop, It looks you 're loading the whole SOF home page Integer.MAX_VALUE times. Of course, this will have memory implications.

Comment: But after each loop i am clearing all history in `webClient` or is there any problem?

Comment: Each time the webClient.getPage is called, htmlunit creates a new window for that page. It is similar to tabs in web browsers. what about adding `webClient.closeAllWindows()`

Comment: method `webClient.closeAllWindows()` is not exist

Answer (score 0):

Did some check with this code and jProfiler and there seems to be no real memory leak at all.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            webClient.getOptions().setHistorySizeLimit(0);

            System.out.println(i);
            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://stackoverflow.com");
            System.out.println(page.getHead().toString());
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: After 1 minute I have memory over 1,5gb. In profiler the most biggist object is some `int[]` ...

Comment: Had the same but after some minutes the used memory goes down to some stable value. I guess we see some JVM effect here. Maybe you can limit the memory using -X to avoid the peak.

Comment: @tiaviode Do you have the same effect or do you still think there is a problem?